# Hartshorne Exercise IV 6.8: should $g\geq 1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The exercise is stated as follows:

> A curve $X$ of genus $g$ has a nonspecial divisor $D$ of degree $d$ such that $|D|$ has no base points if and only if $d\geq g+1$.

But if $g=0$, we know that $X\simeq \mathbb P^1$. In this case $\mathscr L(K)=\mathcal O_X(-2)$, so I think the zero divisor satisfy the condition, but the degree is $0$.

So should we further ask $g$ to be greater than $1$? (or maybe more conditions are needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the exercise as written is not quite right. But we can do better for our proposed remedy. In fact, simply requiring that $D$ is not the zero divisor is enough, and this only affects the situation on $\Bbb P^1$, which is the only place where the issue arises.